# Comparison of these types is not implemented error when filtering a row

Tags: r

Trying to filter a row of df by a given output from previous query -

`sql = 'select max(id) from drivers'` returns `10000`

I have a set of id's from a csv and I would like to filter out from a data fram all referrals that have a referral id that's greater than the `max(id) = 10000` of the above query.

In my code I have:

```
library(tidyverse)

referrals_1 <- import(csv)

df <- referrals_1 %>%
  filter(referrals_2$referral_id < max_driver_id)
```

and keep getting `Error in referrals_2$referral_id < max_driver_id : comparison of these types is not implemented`

When I check the `typeof()` of both `max_driver_id` and `shopper_referral_id` I get `"list"`. I'm a little confused as to what to do to filter out the rows that have a higher id than the max id variable.

Comment: `id` seems it can be of class `"factor"`. What do `class(shopper_referrals_2$shopper_referral_id)` and `class(max_driver_id)` return?

Comment: `id` is class `factor` and `max_driver_id` is `data.frame`. I will look into both of those and how to get them to work together!

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say exactly without a minimal reproducible example but looks like you're referencing the wrong data frame somewhere. Consider:

```
shopper_referrals_2 <- shopper_referrals_1 %>%
  filter(shopper_referrals_2$shopper_referral_id < max_driver_id)
```

What is the purpose of `shopper_referrals_1` if you're trying to filter that to create `shopper_referrals_2` using `shopper_referrals_2` in the `filter` statement? From first glance the code should be corrected to:

```
shopper_referrals_2 <- shopper_referrals_1 %>%
      filter(shopper_referral_id < max_driver_id)
```

where `shopper_referrals_1` is the df you're filtering - `shopper_referral_id` is the column you're filtering within `shopper_referrals_1` and `shopper_referrals_2` is the new df you're creating as a result of the filter.

Comment: Good eye! I did mean `filter(shopper_referrals_1$shopper_referral_id < max_driver_id`. When checking classes of both items I'm filtering I get `shopper_referral_id` is `factor` and `max_driver_id` is `data.frame`

Comment: Best to include a reprex data example. Shooting in the dark otherwise.

Comment: sorry! 

I essentially have two pieces of information: 

A row with numbers like this:
`a, 12

b, 13

c, 163

d, 7363

e, 341

f, 53

g, 24345`

and then a number created from a query that is `1000`. I want to filter that initial set of values by the second piece of information and return all rows that are less than the number pulled from the query